# How do I restore the Run, Save, TidyUp, and JSHint buttons in jsFiddle.net?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I just re-discovered jsFiddle (I've seen it ages ago, but if it weren't for a bad memory I'd have no memory at all, so it was like seeing it for the first time today), and am finding it extremely handy.

However, sometimes in the middle of a "syntax session," the Run, Save, TidyUp, and JSHint buttons disappear. How do I get them to come back?

BTW, I'm using Chrome when I see (or don't see) this happen.

Comment: I think you should rather write a bug report to the developers.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, are you in dashboard mode? What is the url that you are using when you see/don't see the control buttons?

Comment: I don't know - what is dashboard mode, and how do I know that I am in it? The URL is simply jsfiddle.net. I did find, though, that mashing Ctrl+Shift+Up arrow restored the buttons to sight.

Answer (score 3):

Mashing Ctrl+Shift+Up Arrow restores them to visibility.

Comment: Yeah, what the heck. I can't figure out what makes it disappear, though. I'm not doing it on purpose.

Comment: and when this doesn't work?

Comment: This is not working for me on Linux.